# Why do I get "This Safe couldn't be loaded" on Polygon safe?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I keep getting "This Safe couldn't be loaded" error on our DAO's safe. Community's very sad - please send help.

It's a safe on Polygon.

Comment: StackExchange is not a general support channel and only developer support. Please use the support on https://gnosis-safe.io

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.